# Issue with Provisioning profiles for IOS when using Archive for Publishing on VS for Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio

I am trying to Publish my first App for IOS Distribution, on my Macbook Air using VS Studio for Mac V17.4.2 and XCode V14.2.

I have created and downloaded the certificates and provisioning profiles.

When I try the Archive for Publish on VS I get an error:

> Could not find any provisioning profiles for project on IOS

When I look at the project Bundle Signing settings I get following screen:

[image: Archive for Publish Error]

The bundle identfier eg com.companyname.project is the same in project properties and provisioning profile.

The signing certificates for IOS Distribution are loaded into Xcode.

Can anyone please indicate to me as how to resolve the above error.

One thing I am not sure is where VS is looking for the provisioning profile file as it is currently in my downloads folder and I have clicked on.

Thanks

Have tried looking online but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue. The provisioning file was in correctly named.